# Making a single line of text into separate boxes using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to run a single line of text wrapped in a single tag, and then output it with a background colour, breaks into multiple lines encased in a box, and these boxes are translucent that overlapped each other?

I have a demo in [JSFiddle >here<](http://jsfiddle.net/vm7488/fd870om5/).

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p><b>Live a good life. If there are gods and they are just,</b>
    </p>
    <p><b>then they will not care how devout you have been,</b>
    </p>
    <p><b>but will welcome you based on the virtues you have lived by.</b>
    </p>
    <p><b>~Marcus Aurelius</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

That up there is what I wanted to accomplish in terms of looks, but it is ***not*** what I wanted to accomplish in terms of markup.

I needed partcularly this line to break into seperate boxes that overlap:

```
<blockquote class="blue-tape">Live a good life. If there are gods and they are just, 
then they will not care how devout you have been, 
but will welcome you based on the virtues you have lived by. 
Now how do I split these into boxed lines? ~Marcus Aurelius</blockquote>
```

Is this *still* a CSS3 job, or do we need to use JQuery now?

(CSS for all of it)

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    display:block;
}
b {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(78, 145, 220, 0.5);
    color: #55349E;
    font-weight:100;
    padding:10px 1% 18px;
    margin:-10px auto;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    text-align:center;
}
.blue-tape {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(78, 145, 220, 0.5);
    line-height: 1.6677547em;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with what you want to do with just html/css. Even with javascript, if you wanted to modify the css of just a part of a text block, you would need some way to identify it via css selectors.

Comment: I actually just saw a jQuery plugin that splits lines (to enable a single line of text break-words possible for block-by-block animation (https://github.com/jeremyharris/split_lines) Thanks anyway!

Comment: The plugin you linked generates HTML that basically does what your `.wrap` in your question is doing by containing each line within its own element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a span with a background color and extra line-height, to achieve the desired effect: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/6mx6zxxp/))

### CSS

```
span {
    background-color: rgba(78, 145, 220, 0.5);
    line-height:180%;
    padding:.5em 0em;
}
```

### HTML

```
<span>Live a good life. If there are gods and they are just, then they will not care how devout you have been, but will welcome you based on the virtues you have lived by. Now how do I split these into boxed lines?</span>
```

Becomes:

[image: Screenshot of Exampl]

Comment: Play with padding to add extra space between the yellow and the text.

Comment: That simple?  Wow okay, I was overthinking it, hahaha.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution is very good, but is there a way to break lines in the text where you want it to without adding `<br>` tags? I updated your fiddle by adding `<br>`'s to split the lines up as well as containing the `<span>` to center the text just for demonstration. http://jsfiddle.net/6mx6zxxp/2/.

Comment: That's why we have `<br/>`. One can probably develop a JS function that counts characters or matches a string then replaces/adds a break in the text, but that seems excessive as you already know where (between which words) you want the line to break.

Comment: You could also `<pre><span>Text Here</span></pre>` and then use hard returns to create the line breaks instead of `<br/>`. But that method can be unreliable.

Comment: As per the first line of the original question: "Is it possible to run a single line of text wrapped in a single tag, and then output it with..." I was wondering if it was possible to make it look visually how he wanted to with just 1 tag. I guess this is not possible. The `<pre>` method seems to be more in line with what he wants to do, but as you said, it is unreliable.